# Why when i get the month and day value from a date field in Dynamics CRM it is the Month and Day - 1?

Tags: javascript, datetime, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have some funky date values showing in CRM. I am applying a quick fix using javascript to set the date time of the field to the date at 12p noon.

Why when getting the month and day values, the debugger is showing the month and day - 1 as seen below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date.getMonth()` returns the month as a number between 0 and 11, so January would be 0, and December 11.

`date.getDay()` returns the day of the week, where Sunday is 0, Monday is one, and so on.

If you want to get the day of the month, you have to call `date.getDate()`.